# Rails: How to sort/re-order an OrderedHash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, hash

I have an OrderedHash, generated from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269357/rails-efficiently-pull-and-calculate-data-across-several-relationships) that looks like this:

```
<OrderedHash {2=>"534.45",7=>"10",153=>"85.0"}>
```

So, I need to sort the hash by the second value, in descending order.  I tried this:

```
var.sort! {|a,b| b[1] <=> a[1]}
NoMethodError: undefined method `sort!' for #<ActiveSupport::OrderedHash:0x127a50848>
```

How can I reorder this OrderedHash?

Comment: @Shtééf's answer looks good to me but could I suggest treating ruby as ruby and not some other language? It's temping to think you're trying to make ruby look like php, which would be unfortunate. Perhaps you could explain what you're hoping to achieve next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I think you can simply use `:order => 'sum_deal_price ASC'` in the `sum` call of the original answer.

But you can also do it in Ruby, it's just a bit trickier:

```
# You can't sort a Hash directly, so turn it into an Array.
arr = var.to_a  # => [[2, "534.45"], [7, "10"], [153, "85.0"]]
# Looks like there's a bunch of floats-as-strings in there, fix that.
arr.map! { |pair| [pair.first, pair.second.to_f] }
# Now sort it by the value (which is the second entry of the pair).
arr.sort! { |a, b| a.second <=> b.second }
# Turn it back into an OrderedHash.
sorted_hash = ActiveSupport::OrderedHash[arr]
```

Comment: The order by deal.price doesn't seem to work.  The results I get are all over the map compared to the result set.  Using your second suggestion works (except for the sort!, I had to use {|a,b| b[1] <=> a[1]} ), but I'm concerned about the time.  I'm looking at 80,000 records, and converting them back and forth takes quite a while.

Comment: Whoops, good catch. Fixed the sort call. I'm not sure if this'll work, but could you try `:order => 'sum_deal_price'`? (Or check in the log what alias name is assigned to the SUM result column.)

Comment: That did it. I was able to return the values that I needed with just a sql statement.  Thanks!